# How to jQuery - Add button insert maximum 10 new inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to click on my button and insert every click new input and when up to 10 just stop . I have done with one input lets check my code :
HTML code

```
    <div class="form-group ">
    <label for="email2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Occupants Email Address :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email2" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <span class="addMore">ADD</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group addmore2">
    <label for="emailOccup2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Occupants Email Address 2 :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailOccup2" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 removeEmail">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span> remove
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.addmore2 {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.addMore').click(function() {
    $('.addmore2').slideDown();
})

$('.removeEmail').click(function() {
    $('.addmore2').slideUp();
});
```

I know how to insert just one , somebody help what function I need to use to make it uo to 10.
Thanks!

Comment: can you please supply a working jsfiddle or jsbin with all the CSS classes.   Also, are you asking how to hide/show 10 sections like '.addmore2'?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the implementation below, which was heavily adapted from [Add/Remove Input Fields Dynamically with jQuery](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery).

Your goal here is to keep track of the number of fields that have been added. Once the number of fields (represented by x) exceeds ten, the append method will no longer function.

On each click, we are incrementing the number of fields by one.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initial text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append(
                '<div class="form-group"><label>Occupants Email Address :</label><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/></div><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
            ); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

Here's the corresponding HTML

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
    <div class="form-group"><label>Occupants Email Address :</label><div class="col-sm-3"><input type="text" name="mytext[]"/></div>
</div>
```

Here's a working jsFiddle: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjatkinson2/jnbg1k3t/)

Answer (score 0):

here is a basic example

```js
var iteration = 0,
    addEmail = document.querySelector("#addEmail");

addEmail.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if(iteration < 10){
    var input =document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "email"; 
    input.placeholder = "Email"
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    iteration++
  }
},false);
```

```html
<input id=addEmail type=button value="add Email input" />
```

Using jquery you could do something like

```js
var iteration = 0;

$("#addEmail").click(function() {
  if (iteration < 10) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.type = "email";
    input.placeholder = "Email"
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    iteration++
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=addEmail type=button value="add Email input" />
```

Comment: Thanks I got it what is idea :)